# My server keeps sending emails to hostmaster@xxx.com

Tags: linux, email, postfix

When I type mailq on my server, I get:

```
BB523653A62     4025 Wed Jun  4 10:40:07  MAILER-DAEMON
(delivery temporarily suspended: host p3smtpout.secureserver.net[208.109.80.54] refused to talk to me: 554 p3plsmtpout002.prod.phx3.secureserver.net : DED : AJeb1o0334uf1Y801 : DED : You've reached your daily relay quota - IP.ADDRESS)
                                         hostmaster@MYDOMAIN.COM

B33AD653A4A     4025 Wed Jun  4 08:20:07  MAILER-DAEMON
(delivery temporarily suspended: host p3smtpout.secureserver.net[208.109.80.54] refused to talk to me: 554 p3plsmtpout002.prod.phx3.secureserver.net : DED : AJeb1o0334uf1Y801 : DED : You've reached your daily relay quota - IP.ADDRESS)
                                         hostmaster@MYDOMAIN.COM

B77DF653A63     4025 Wed Jun  4 10:50:07  MAILER-DAEMON
(delivery temporarily suspended: host p3smtpout.secureserver.net[208.109.80.54] refused to talk to me: 554 p3plsmtpout001.prod.phx3.secureserver.net : DED : AJvF1o00L4uf1Y801 : DED : You've reached your daily relay quota - IP.ADDRESS)
                                         hostmaster@MYDOMAIN.COM

B943C653A3C     4025 Wed Jun  4 06:40:07  MAILER-DAEMON
(delivery temporarily suspended: host p3smtpout.secureserver.net[208.109.80.54] refused to talk to me: 554 p3plsmtpout001.prod.phx3.secureserver.net : DED : AKBv1o00P4uf1Y801 : DED : You've reached your daily relay quota - IP.ADDRESS)
                                         hostmaster@MYDOMAIN.COM
```

(there is probably about 50 of these, and I've cleared the queue today), do you know where these could be coming from ? is it my server sending some logs to "hostmaster" ?
I've replaced my actual domain, with "MYDOMAIN".

How can I find what could be sending these emails ? The server has recently been hacked so I'm also a bit worried.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried _reading_ one of the emails?

Comment: I'm just an engineer working for a client, hostmaster does not exist, and I would prefer avoiding bothering the manager who is away on vacation.

Comment: If you can run mailq you can probably read the email when they're in the queue. I think you're using postfix, but you might be using exim. The syntax for exim is "exim -Mrm <id>" where id is the nonsense number at the beginning of each mailq line. For postfix the command appears to be "postcat -vq <id>" where id is again the funky B77DF653A63 thing.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure your server isn't acting as an open relay. You can use http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx# with the Test Email Server option.

Comment: Doesn't look like it, no real errors there :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is what was the issue and how I fixed it:

Thanks to "Some Linux Nerd"'s comment, I was able to figure out what the email was.

First I paused the emails from being sent:

```
sudo postconf -e defer_transports=smtp;sudo postfix reload
```

Then I waited until I see a few emails in the queue using:

```
mailq
```

I got the ID of one of the emails, and then I used this to see the email entirely:

```
postcat -vq <id>
```

This allowed me to see that the email was actually sent by cron. And that I forgot to add this at the end of every cron:

```
>/dev/null 2>&1

For example it can be used like:

* * * * * SOMECOMMAND >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And then don't forget to renable postfix to send emails:

```
sudo postconf -e defer_transports=;sudo postfix reload;sudo postfix flush
```